# How to open XPS files in Firefox

Tags: firefox, xps-viewer

I'm trying to find a way to open XPS files in a Firefox tab.
I'm able to open them in Internet Explorer, but I would like them to open directly in Firefox without having to switch application.

I've tried to configure an IE Tab extension, but it doesn't work.

I'd like detailed instructions to do so, if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is also a standalone XPS viewer available from Microsoft, if you are unaware of it.  It is the default XPS viewer on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the IE tab addin for Firefox
2. Install it
3. Then the clever bit open options
4. Set up a URL thus: /^file:///.*.(xps)$/

Source: [http://geekswithblogs.net/ajames/archive/2008/11/08/reading-xps-files-using-firefox-3.x.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20180425122913/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ajames/archive/2008/11/08/reading-xps-files-using-firefox-3.x.aspx)
IETab: [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419/](https://web.archive.org/web/20171204175044/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419/)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not just one IE tabs, but many . And none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

When XPS Viewer is installed, it adds filters to the system to view and render .xps files.  No time was put into making a graphical interface for XPS... so there is no "XPS-viewer". Instead the files are linked to the default browser (supposed to be IE) and IE loads the filter/drivers and renders the file.

The problem happens when a second browser is installed and takes the default browser setting. Then "XPS-viewer" settings passes the file to the new browser which does not load the drivers and handle it.

So, change the default application from "XPS Viewer" to Internet Explorer. That is the expected behavior and corrects the problem.

File Properties -> General Tab ->"Opens With", Change button. Set the application to Internet Explorer and it will open the XPS files.