# How do I print from Windows 7 to Uniguest?

Tags: windows-7, printing

Some Marriott-brand hotels (like Courtyard etc), amongst others, have this poorly-designed and very limiting kiosk software installed called Uniguest.

On some of their machines don't appear to allow you to open up XPS files (whilst others do).  My Windows 7 ThinkPad, however, can only produce XPS files when I try to print something to a file.

What's the best way to print from a Windows 7 laptop to a Uniguest hotel kiosk?

Is there a way to make Uniguest open up XPS files properly?  (The application selection feature appears disabled within the interface of the kiosk.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Uniguest supports PDF. Office and many other programs like Chrome for example can save as/export to PDF. For others that don't have this option you can install a PDF printer such as [this](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) or [this](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp).

Edit: To turn on XPS support in Windows 7:

1. In the Start Menu search box type "windows features" and select *Turn Windows features on or off*.
2. Check **XPS Services** and **XPS Viewer** and OK your way out.

Comment: Isn't XPS supposed to be openable within Internet Explorer itself, according to http://superuser.com/questions/227262/how-to-open-xps-files-in-firefox?  Why did Uniguest go to such great lengths to inconvenience the travellers by disabling such basic functionality within Windows?

Comment: XPS Viewer and Services need to be installed via Windows Features for the format to be supported. Those systems probably don't have these but only the people in charge can answer why.

Comment: i actually called the support number at the bottom of the screen, and was connected to some guy in Nashville, TN (or something like that).  Provided property phone number, and he went in as an administrator, and tried to fix it.  It was somewhat complicated of a fix, not many manuals how to fix anywhere on the net, and it remained not working in the guest account, only fully working in the admin one.  If you could possibly elaborate / include parts of this in the answer, that'd be great.

Comment: I don't know what that admin was doing but seems pretty straight-forward to me (see the edit above). Also, did you try PDFs instead?